# Does Bash and Zsh have a mode to echo what the alias expands to upon pressing Enter?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

For example, if I have a

```
alias dbmigrate='rails db:migrate'
```

is there a mode or simple way to configure in Bash and Zsh so that when I type in the shell:

```
$ dbmigrate  # press Enter
```

it will echo what the alias expands to before running it?

Comment: In `fish`, you can use `abbr` instead of `alias`. It will expand the abbreviated commands upon execution.

Comment: Late to the party, but this may be useful for those who stumble across this from a search engine. If you want to know what the command does without executing you can call `which dbmigrate`. This will echo something like `dbmigrate: aliased to rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 4):

In **bash**, there are the `alias-expand-line` and `history-and-alias-expand-line` readline functions, but they aren't bound to any keys by default. You can bind them yourself -- example with `Control-T`:

```
bind '"\C-T": history-and-alias-expand-line'
```

Trying to bind `Enter` itself is would be messy, because not anytime you press `Enter` you have the command executed (eg. not when it's an incomplete pipeline, etc).

There's also the `DEBUG` trap, but determining whether the command was actually entered by the user (eg. not started from `PROMPT_COMMAND` or from a command substitution in `PS1`), and whether it was alias-expanded is going to be tricky; but if you're OK with it printing *any* command before being executed:

```
trap 'echo "> $BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG

bash$ pwd
> pwd
```

---

In **zsh**, you can simply define a `preexec` function which prints the expanded command if different from the one entered by the user:

```
preexec(){ [ $1 != $2 ] && print -r "> $2" }

zsh$ j
> jobs
```

---

Beware however that some alias + history tricks won't work properly if you force-expand the alias. For instance, I have an `c` alias in bash to do calculations like `c 3.17 * 4.2`, without having to escape the `*`, `(`, etc:

```
alias c='_c=$(fc -nl -0); bc -l <<<${_c#*c} #'
```

Once readline has expanded it, the current line from the history (the one returned by `fc -nl -0`) will be the *expanded*, not the original command, and everything will fall apart.

Comment: my question is not really about "binding" something to the Enter key... it just means, can Bash and Zsh echo what command it is running before running it

Comment: And my answer shows you how to do that (with the DEBUG trap in bash and with preexec in zsh) shows some of their limitations and gotchas, and a possible alternative. You know, you're like, huh, supposed to read it before commenting on it. If you know a way to also get the unexpanded command in bash (just like in zsh, with the 2nd argument of preexec) just show it. I'm interested too!

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are just simple substitutions. If you want to do something fancier, like print a message before running the command, you need something more powerful: a function. If you want the definition to look like an alias definition, you can define a function that defines a function.

```
function verbose_alias {
  local name=${1%%=*} expansion=${1#*=}
  eval "function $name {
    printf >&2 '%s is an alias for %s\\n' \"$name\" \"$expansion\";
    $expansion \"\$@\";
  }"
}
verbose_alias dbmigrate='rails db:migrate'
```

Comment: but I am not looking for a function... I want a way so that my alias is expanded and shown as to what is going to be done

Answer (score 2):

POSIX requires the [`set` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/set.html) to have this option

> `-x`
>
> The shell shall write to standard error a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes it. It is unspecified whether the command that turns tracing off is traced.
>
> https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/set.html

So you can just use `set -x` or `set -o xtrace` on any compatible shells. In bash you can see this in the man page:

> `-x`
>
> After expanding each simple command, for command, case command, select command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or associated word list.
>
> `xtrace`
>
> Same as `-x`.
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

zsh also has a similar option for the [`set` builtin](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins)

> **XTRACE** (`-x`, ksh: `-x`)
>
> Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions

You can also specify the `-x` option while executing scripts or commands

```
bash -x -c "echo This will be printed before running; ll"
bash -x script-to-be-debugged.sh
zsh -x -c "...; 3; md did-you-see-the-aliases"
zsh -x buggy-script.sh
```

Beware that it also expands the commands that are run before and after each prompt so it may be not desirable in many situations, for example when you use `git` variables in your PS1. In my clean Ubuntu VM only the running command is printed out

See also [What does `set -x` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36273665/995714)

Another option is `set -v` or `set -o verbose` which doesn't expand the variables before printing

Answer (score 0):

That kind of help is not available by default in bash.

The two related functions that are available by default are:

- `shopt -s histverify`

> If  set,  and  readline is being used, the results of history substitution are not immediately passed to the shell parser.  Instead, the resulting line is loaded into the  readline  editing buffer, allowing further modification.

Which addresses the part of an action when `Enter` is pressed, but only with an history expansion on the command line. For example:

```
$ shopt -s histverify
$ echo "this is a test"
This is a test
$ echo !!
$ echo echo "this is a test"  <---- expanded by the simple use of enter!!
```

- Readline `shell-expand-line`

> shell-expand-line (M-C-e)

> Expand  the  line  as the shell does.  This performs alias and history expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions.  See HISTORY EXPANSION below for a description of history expansion.

This is exactly what you are asking for to be done, but the key to make it work is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>

I am not aware of a solution that works with enter and executes `shell-expand-line`, sorry.